# Can I use a dplyr pipe instead of lapplying over lists in R?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, data-manipulation

I'd like to know if I can use tidyverse for tasks I used lists in R so far.
I got a matrix of species abundances per plot for which I want to calculate dissimilarity  indices with *vegdist* from the *vegan* package. After that I'd like to put it in long format remove auto comparisons etc.
It works like charm with *dplyr* for an easy example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)
df <- data.frame(spec1=sample.int(50,10,replace=T),
             spec2=sample.int(75,10,replace=T),
             spec3=sample.int(10,10,replace=T),
             spec4=sample.int(40,10,replace=T),
             spec5=sample.int(50,10,replace=T),
             spec6=sample.int(5,10,replace=T))

 df%>%
  vegdist() %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as_tibble(rownames= "rownames") %>%
  pivot_longer(-rownames) %>%
  filter(rownames < name)
```

Now I want to do the same however the species belong to different categories and each category has to get its own distance matrix and only after it can be put back to a single long format data frame or tibble.

```
cat <- data.frame(spec=c("spec1","spec2","spec3","spec4","spec5","spec6"),
                  group=c("a","b","c","b","a","c"))
df%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),values_to="abundance",names_to="spec")%>%
  left_join(cat, by="spec")
```

The beginning is pretty straight forward but at the point where I am used to split the data to a list by the column *group* I am struggling to find a solution. I tried combinations of *group_by* + *pivot_wider* + *vegdist* or also *group_split* but unfortunately wasn't able to come up with a working solution. Does anybody have suggestions, or should I stick with lists for such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may `split` the 'spec' by 'group' into a `list`, loop over the `list` and then `select` the columns based on the elements from the `list` and apply the `vegdist`

```
library(vegan)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- map_dfr(split(cat$spec, cat$group), 
   ~  df %>%
         select(all_of(.x)) %>% 
         vegdist() %>% 
         as.matrix %>% 
         as_tibble(rownames = "rownames") %>% 
        pivot_longer(-rownames) %>% 
        filter(rownames < name), .id = 'group')
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 135 × 4
   group rownames name   value
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
 1 a     1        2     0.268 
 2 a     1        3     0.35  
 3 a     1        4     0.208 
 4 a     1        5     0.0682
 5 a     1        6     0.328 
 6 a     1        7     0.196 
 7 a     1        8     0.189 
 8 a     1        9     0.178 
 9 a     1        10    0.178 
10 a     2        3     0.0822
# … with 125 more rows
```

---

If we want a wide format,

```
cat %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = spec, values_fn = list) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~
    df %>%
     select(all_of(unlist(.x))) %>% 
     vegdist() %>%
     as.matrix %>%
     as_tibble(rownames = "rownames") %>% 
     pivot_longer(-rownames) %>%
     filter(rownames < name))) %>% 
     unnest(where(is.list),  names_sep = "_")
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer I haven't come across map_dfr until now but it looks mighty. the unnest part of the second chunk gives me an error: "Error: Assigned data `map(data[[col]], as_df, col = col)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 45 rows.
x Assigned data has 3 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled." maybe you can edit that before I accept the answer?

Comment: @NR is this error based on a different data or from the same example?   I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.2.0’`

Comment: Thanks for the hint it did not work with tidyr 1.1.3 but after the update it does. The error was based on the sample data.